# fscanf reads only zeros

Tags: c, file-io

I am trying to read data from a .txt file, in which the formatting is like that

```
1.671346 4.064608 -3.861660 
2.891781 -3.505203 0.733207 
-2.033906 -3.854335 -2.194739 
1.726585 -4.220862 3.629719
```

Each of the N rows contains the x,y,z coordinates of a particle, and I intend to store them in a N*3 dimensional array.

However, when I try to read my data, my coordinates array is filled with zeros.

Here is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void leggiFile(FILE *fp, int nrighe, double c[]){
int i;
 for(i=0;i<nrighe;i=i+3){
  fscanf(fp, "%lf %lf %lf", &c[i], &c[i+1], &c[i+2]);
  printf("%lf",c[i]);
 }
}

int main(){
 FILE* fp=fopen("CoordinateMC.txt","r");
 double coord[1500]={0};
 int nrighe=500; 
 leggiFile(fp, nrighe, coord);
}
```

It prints only `0.00000`

I tried switching all the "%lf" into "%f" and switching all the "&c[stuff]" into "c[stuff]"

I suspect that this doesn't work because of something withing my IDE (code::blocks) that I didn't set properly. But the program I ran to generate the .txt file worked like a charm!

Comment: Did you check the file opened? What was the return value from `fscanf`? was it `3`?

Comment: No, it returns -1. This is indeed very picturesque

Comment: And what did `fopen` return? Was it `NULL`?

Comment: fopen returns 1985562240% and stuff like that in general

Comment: Note that the `-1` returned by `fscanf` is `EOF` end of file. *"If an error occurs, or if the end of the file stream is reached before the first conversion, the return value is EOF"*

Comment: Please post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem. This should also show the `#include` files you are using. You might benefit by reading the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: It should be fine now.

Comment: Sorry it does not compile. There is a missing `}` brace somewhere and in `nrighe=500; ` the variable has not been defined. Apart from that it works perfectly here.

Comment: Ok, I fixed it for the second time.

You say it works on your computer, so why shouldn't on mine? I guess the problem is with code::blocks, then.

Comment: Most of the zeros are from the 0-initialised array. You asked for 500 conversions, but the file only contains 4 lines. Change the loop to `while(fscanf(fp, "%lf %lf %lf", &c[i], &c[i+1], &c[i+2]) == 3) {  printf("%lf",c[i]);  i+=3;}`. Always be cautious when blaming the tools you use!

Comment: `fopen("CoordinateMC.txt"` try specifying full path to the file. Maybe you opened wrong file?

Comment: @KamilCuk OP's file did open (see the comment) but he should check it every time. Saves a lot of grief.

Comment: I changed the loop as you told me and now the program has no output.

Comment: Oh, not easy to put in comment, I posted a modified program now.

Comment: Does the code you posted also not work? It worked for me, all I did was tidied it up really. But it was not an MCVE - it didn't compile, so you can't have tried that code.

Comment: Neither your code nor mine work.

Comment: regarding: `double coord[1500]={0};` and `fscanf(fp, "%lf %lf %lf", &c[i], &c[i+1], &c[i+2]);`   1) should use a two dimensional array I.E. ``double coord[500][3]={0};`  then the function: `leggiFile()` should be: `void leggiFile(FILE *fp, int nrighe, double c[][3]] )`  then the call to `fscanf()`  should be: `fscanf(fp, "%lf %lf %lf", &c[i][0], &c[i][1], &c[i][2]);`  3) should be checking the returned value from `fscanf()`, anything other than 3 indicates an error occurred

Comment: Regarding: `FILE* fp=fopen("CoordinateMC.txt","r");`  The next lines should be: `if( !fp )  { perror( "fopen failed" ); exit( EXIT_FAILURE ); }`   Suggest reading the MAN pages for: `fopen()` `perror()` and `exit()`

Comment: it is a poor programming practice to let the OS cleanup after a program.  Suggest at the end of `main()` insert the statement; `fclose( fp );`

Comment: the variable: `nrighe` is actually a constant value.  Suggest using a `#define MAX_ROWS 500 at the top of the program, then remove all references to `nrighe` and have the `for()` loop use `MAX_ROWS` as the limiter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The program only needed a few small changes, where commented. It was printing the correct results, but didn't stop so all you saw was a forest of `0.00000`. The major thing is to *check the result* of I/O operations.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void leggiFile(FILE *fp, int nrighe, double c[]){
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < nrighe; i = i + 3){
        if(fscanf(fp, "%lf %lf %lf", &c[i], &c[i+1], &c[i+2]) != 3) {
            break;                          // conversion was unsuccessful
        }
        printf("%f\n",c[i]);                // removed the `l` from `lf`
    }
}

int main(void){                             // correct definition of maiin
    FILE* fp = fopen("CoordinateMC.txt", "r");
    if(fp == NULL) {                        // check the file opebned
        perror("Cannot open file");
        exit(1);
    }
    double coord[1500] = { 0 };
    int nrighe = 500; 
    leggiFile(fp, nrighe, coord);
    fclose(fp);                             // tidy up
}
```

Program output:

```
1.671346
2.891781
-2.033906
1.726585
```

However I wonder if you posted your actual code that was giving a problem, because you said the `fscanf` returned `-1` which it only does if there is not input data.

Comment: I'm really really grateful for your help and patience, but the program still prints nothing :(

Comment: Does a simple one-line program that outputs a `double` value work?

Comment: No wait! Your code works wonders. There must be another problem indeed

Comment: Ok, I managed to fix it. The problem was with another function that I wrote to count the lines of the input file.

Sorry for all the hassle, it was something mighty stupid! Once I'm done with this assignment I'll try to find out why *that* function breaks everything.

Once again, thank you for all the help

Comment: The function would be better as `int leggiFile` which does `return i;` so the caller knows how much was read.

Answer (score 0):

That's an old function that i have made for the uni, it checks if the file exists then it create and print a new array with the floats in the file, it uses also another function that counts how many numbers are in the file.

questa è una vecchia funzione per l'uni, controlla se il file esiste crea e stampa un array di float del file e usa una funzione ausiliaria che serve a contare in numeri del file, potresti facilmente modificare la funzione per farla funzionare con le matrici o anche più semplicemente riscrivere il file originale in modo che sia un array.

```
void leggiDaFile() {
int n;              // la dimensione dell'array
float reale;        // un numero
n = dimensioneFile();               //crea una funzione che ti permette di contare i numeri presenti
FILE* fp = fopen("FILE.txt", "r");  //metti il tuo file
if(fp==NULL) {
    printf("Non ci sono numeri reali da leggere!"); //verifica esistenza file
}
else {
    if(n==0) 
        printf("Non ci sono numeri reali da leggere!");
    else {
        int i=0;                // contatore
        float reali[n];     // i numeri reali da leggere
        while(fgetc(fp)!=EOF){
            fscanf(fp, "%f", &reale);
            reali[i]=reale;
            i++;
        }
        fclose(fp);
        printf("Ecco i numeri reali: ");
        for(i=0; i<n; i++)
            printf("%.2f  ", reali[i]);
    }
}
```

}